# `__set_name__` hook manually added to `functools.wraps()` descriptor instance never called

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, metaclass, python-descriptors

I'm trying to add a [`__set_name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set_name__) hook to the descriptor produced by [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) inside a decorator, but it is never called and I don't see any error messages:

```py
import functools


def wrap(fn):
    """Decorator."""

    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def w(*args, **kwargs):
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    # This never gets called.
    def set_name(self, obj, name):
        print(f"inside __set_name__: {self=}, {obj=}, {name=}")

    w.__set_name__ = set_name.__get__(w)
    return w


class Foo:
    @wrap
    def foo(self):
        pass
```

From what I understand, `wrap()` is called and its return value bound to the `foo` variable in the class's execution frame before the `Foo` class is created, so the `__set_name__` hook should be in place by the time Python looks for it.  So why isn't it being called?

Comment: Double-underscored special methods are generally looked up on the class, and won't be seen if you add them directly to an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever Python looks for magic methods, it looks on the *type* of the object, not the instance. What you've done is take a `function` object (the return value of `functools.wrap`, in this case) and assign something on its `__dict__`. But for efficiency (and correctness, in some cases), special methods like `__set_name__` bypass `__dict__` and look on the type object directly. See [Special method lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup) for details and a rationale.

To make your code work, you need to create a custom callable class (i.e. a class which defines a function called `__call__`), define `__set_name__` on *that* class, and then make `w` an instance of that class.